# NN multidim regression with matrix as output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression

I want to build a simple NN for regression purposes; the dimension of my input data reads (100000,3): meaning I have 1mio particles and their corresponding x,y,z coordinates. Out of these particles I want to predict centers which the particles correspond to where the data of the centers read (1000,3).

my question is: since the input array should have the same number of samples as target arrays how can I solve this problem?

actually my mapping is from (100000,3) -> (1000,3) because on average about 100 particles belong to one center.

to train the model i will use many of those datasets with the right centers as output; after that i want to predict out of one new set of particle coordinates the corresponding centers.

Comment: NN is one of the supervised machine learning models. One element in the input has a corresponding element in the output. In practice, you have to provide both matrices/vectors of the same size, in your case (1000000, ). As your output has a fewer number of elements, you will end up with repeated values in the output. I hope I understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to match the sizes. Assuming you know what particle belongs to what center that shouldn't be too hard.

So in your case you should have a matrix of (1000000,3)(atoms) and a vector of (1000000,)(centers) as their labels. This means that each entry in the vector corresponds to one row in the atom matrix.

Comment: the problem is that i have no labeling; so i do not know which particle belongs to which center.. can i solve this in another way? or do you think this is doable with a neural network?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to a question regarding unknown labels.

You have to know labels before using any supervised algorithm. Otherwise, there is no way you can train a model. You need to think of solving this problem by employing one of the unsupervised techniques, such as *k*-means algorithm, Gaussian Mixture Models, or Classification And Regression Trees, etc.

For example, one of the suggestions I would give is to try k-means with a fixed number of *k*, which is 1000 in your case, run the algorithm a couple of times and see if centroids are any close to elements in your output. Then, you could classify your output based on how close they are to one of the nearest centroids. Then all elements of input belonging to individual centroids would be classified as such.

---

EDIT.

After reconsidering your example, I think that perhaps *k*-NN would be much more helpful to your problem. In *k*-NN, outputs are considered as neighbours. Each point from the input is assigned to the closest neighbour. In the end, you already have the output but you don't know how to map all elements in both the input and the output. I have just realised your problem is "the mapping". It is a good chance *k*-NN would solve that meaning it would create labels for all elements in the input that correspond to elements in the output. Once it is done, the Neural Network model can be trained.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will try this approach and keep you informed wheather it worked or not..

Comment: one more question regarding this: do you think kmeans would also do the job instead of knn? with kmeans i also could calculate the centroids and then try to relate them to the real centers from my dataset

Comment: @jeffs I am sorry. I am afraid I confused _k_-means with _k_-NN. I meant to apply an unsupervised algorithm, which is _k_-means, while _k_-NN is one of the supervised techniques. I will edit my answer as I have an idea about your problem as well.

Comment: I tried kmeans for a small dataset to check wheather the centroids correspond to each other. But then i thought again about my dataset of centers and realized that these are centers for low density regions and not as in kmeans the averaged coordinates of one cluster. is there any unsupervised algorithm which detects for low dense regions? after that, do you still think knn could work?

Comment: and you are right, my problem is actually the mapping between input and output to feed in in a neural network. but i didnt get the whole idea how knn would solve this mapping

Comment: @jeffs k-NN determines a class of each input it belongs to by estimating its neighbourhood and taking sort of voting. There are different methods of that but the most common is by considering the first _K_ closest outputs and taking the one of the highest frequency. In your case, _K_ should be equal to 1 because you have only one point per class.
Last thought. In your case, how about just iterating over all inputs and assigning each of them to the closest centroid?

Comment: when trying knn I always get the error: "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples" . since the input (in my case (100000,3)) and the output (1000,3) have not the same dimensions how can I avoid this problem? I think both must have dimensions to run the code

Comment: Unless I miss something obvious or don't fully understand how k-NN works, or it is something particular with a framework you are using, honestly, I don't know the reason for this error. You may want to define only three neighbours. Then, why would you need the same size of both the input and the output?

Comment: Perhaps it could be a good idea to share your code here or even better you could ask a new particular question regarding your code and the framework you work with. You could explain what the code is for, what is the bigger picture, and get even better answers than mine. However, don't repeat the same question as it will be closed due to a duplicate. Also, don't ask the same question in different Stack Exchange sites. Generally, It gets vots to close due to cross-posting but not always.